# how to trigger an event when data is loaded in a Nativescript Listview

Tags: listview, nativescript

I have read the docs here https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events and https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding but i am not seeing how I can bind an event to a listview when data has started or completed loading. I want to know when to show/hide the page loading graphic. I now use a setimeout but that is not ideal as whenthe connection is fast the loader is still showing the loader which is not needed and the opposite when the connection is slow.

```
exports.pageLoadedRequest = () => {
loadingIndicator.show();
setTimeout(()=>{
    welcomeViewModel.empty("all");
    welcomeViewModel.getExposuresData({onNavigatingTo:true}).then((response)=>{
        const month1 = page.getViewById("month1");
        const month2 = page.getViewById("month2");
        const month3 = page.getViewById("month3");
        const month4 = page.getViewById("month4");
        const tabs = page.getViewById("tabs");

        //update view elements and bindingcontext
        month1.text = response.monthNames._array[0];
        month2.text = response.monthNames._array[1];
        month3.text = response.monthNames._array[2];
        month4.text = response.monthNames._array[3];
        tabs.selectedIndex=response.autoSelectedIndex;
        previouslyTappedItem = response.autoSelectedIndex + 1;

        page.bindingContext = response;

        //run the counter now
        welcomeViewModel.getRefreshCount({onNavigatingTo:true});
    });

    setTimeout(()=>{
        loadingIndicator.hide();
        onNavigatingTo = false;
    },5000);

},50)
}
```

I know there is a better way. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you referring to loading data on demand at end of scroll, I think you should use RadListView for this purpose - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/RadListView/load-on-demand

Comment: No I am not referring to loading nw data at the end of a scroll. I chose listview instead of radlistview because radlistview would be an overkill for what I need. Further more my app require tabs component with four tabs. Each tab with a listview. I read that the listview was more economical on memory so I chose that. I just want a better way to show/hide  loadingIndicator without using a settimeout. I want to hook into an event that can tell me when data has arrived or loaded whenever a call is made to get new data for the list view.

Comment: Rendering a list should be instant, you would just have to show / hide loading indicator while fetching remote data. You could hide indicator upon response for the http request.